# Access 2007 Reports - How to 'unfix' fields?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm fairly experienced with MS Access 2003,  but 2007 has a new feature that is confusing me.

I'm maintaining an Access database with a variety of reports.  Some of these reports have fields with constraints on where I can move them.  If I move a field vertically, ALL the fields in that section must move with it. If I move a field horizontally, it automatically switches with the field next to it.

This is clearly a feature since it makes *some* kinds of reports easier, but it's just getting in my way now since I need to have detail fields on 2 lines.  Can someone tell me what this thing is called and (more importantly) how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is known as "Control Layouts."  Here's how to get rid of them:

> **Remove controls from a control layout**
> Removing a control from a
> control layout allows you to place it anywhere on the report without
> affecting the positioning of any other controls.
>
> - Select the control you want to remove from the layout. To select
>   multiple controls, hold down the SHIFT key and then click the controls
>   that you want to remove. To select all of the controls in the layout,
>   click the layout selector box at the top left corner of the layout.
> - Do
>   one of the following:
>
>   - On the Arrange tab, in the Control Layout group,
>     click Remove.
>   - Right-click one of the selected controls, point to
>     Layout, and then click Remove. Access removes the selected controls
>     from the layout.
>
> TIP   To prevent a control from being inserted into
> a control layout as you move it, press and hold the CTRL key, and then
> drag the control to where you want it.

The full documentation for the above excerpt can be found here: [Modify, edit, or change a report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/modify-edit-or-change-a-report-HA010014117.aspx#BMcrmdv)